# How to split up an array into 2 different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Ive got an array with URLs in it like so:

```
$urls = array("http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part1.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part2.rar", "http://myurl/file/2222/file.part3.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part4.rar");
```

I want to find any of the filenames to check if they are a part or a single file.

For example the result for the above should be:

```
$single = "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.rar";
$splits = array("http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part1.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part2.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part3.rar", "http://myurl.com/file/2222/file.part4.rar");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im thinking i need to use in_array somehow but i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: How easily can you predict the file name?  Do they follow a standard convention?

Comment: Yes they are always either NAME.rar or NAME.part.rar so i need to get all the URLS with part into one array and all the urls without part into another array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like `preg_grep()`:

```
$parts = preg_grep('/\.part\d+\.rar/', $urls);
$singles = array_diff($urls, $parts);
```

Or to do the opposite for the singles:

```
$singles = preg_grep('/\.part\d+\.rar/', $urls, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Comment: Really nice! i used the first script, works really well. Will accept as soon as it lets me.